# MongoDB in "subscribe" on Redis

Tags: mongodb, redis, real-time, node-redis

Is it possible to configure an architecture with Redis in "master" and MongoDB in "slave" in order to automatically persist in MongoDB some volatile information in Redis?

Example: persist in MongoDB a list of notifications for a user created in Redis.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

However, you could imagine to maintain a synchronization list in Redis to queue all the changes that have to be sent to MongoDB. Then, you can add a daemon listening to the Redis synchronization list, and applying the changes to MongoDB.

The implementation of a true guaranteed delivery mechanism (i.e. once and only once semantic) is difficult though.